# Keyboard Only Allows Bottom Sheet to Open Half Way

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, search, android-recyclerview

I am having an issue where the keyboard makes it so that the bottom sheet only shows up half way(See first photo). I would like to have it so that when the user clicks the search bar, the bottom sheet always expands to the top of the page and the keyboard is then present(See photo 2). I thought the issue was in the STATE_EXPANDED and somehow disabling the keyboard but this did not work.Any assistance would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

```
class CustomBottomSheetBehavior<T : View>(private val context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) :
    BottomSheetBehavior<T>(context, attrs), GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {

    private lateinit var customBottomSheetCallback: CustomBottomSheetCallback<T>

    private val  gestureDetector = GestureDetector(context, this)
    interface BottomSheetStateChangeListener {
        fun changeBottomSheetState(state: Int)
    }

    fun setupCallback(listener: BottomSheetStateChangeListener) {
        customBottomSheetCallback = CustomBottomSheetCallback(this, listener)
        this.setBottomSheetCallback(customBottomSheetCallback)
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(parent: CoordinatorLayout, child: T, event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
//        gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)
        return super.onTouchEvent(parent, child, event)
    }

    override fun onDown(motionEvent: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    override fun onShowPress(motionEvent: MotionEvent) {

    }

    override fun onSingleTapUp(motionEvent: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        state = STATE_EXPANDED
        return false
    }

    override fun onScroll(
        motionEvent: MotionEvent,
        motionEvent1: MotionEvent,
        v: Float,
        v1: Float
    ): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    override fun onLongPress(motionEvent: MotionEvent) {

    }

    override fun onFling(
        motionEvent: MotionEvent,
        motionEvent1: MotionEvent,
        v: Float,
        v1: Float
    ): Boolean {
        if(motionEvent.y < motionEvent1.y) {
            Log.d("onFling", "down swipe")
            customBottomSheetCallback.directFling = DirectFling.Down
        } else {
            Log.d("onFling", "up swipe")
            customBottomSheetCallback.directFling = DirectFling.UP
        }
        return false
    }

    enum class DirectFling {
        UP, Down
    }

    internal inner class CustomBottomSheetCallback<T : View>(private val bottomSheetBehavior: CustomBottomSheetBehavior<T>, private val listener: BottomSheetStateChangeListener) :
        BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {

        // 4(Collapsed) or 3(Expanded) or 6(Half_Expanded)
        var preState = 4

        var directFling: DirectFling? = null

        private var offset: Float = 0.toFloat()

        override fun onStateChanged(view: View, state: Int) {

            if(state == STATE_SETTLING) {
                when(preState) {
                    STATE_COLLAPSED -> {
                        if (directFling == DirectFling.UP) {
                            bottomSheetBehavior.state = STATE_EXPANDED
                        }
                    }

                    STATE_EXPANDED -> {
                        if (directFling == DirectFling.Down) {
                            bottomSheetBehavior.state =  STATE_COLLAPSED

                        }
                    }
                }

            }

            if (state == STATE_COLLAPSED) {
                preState = STATE_COLLAPSED
                listener.changeBottomSheetState(STATE_HIDDEN)
                Log.d("state collapse", "full collapsed")

                //Collapse keyboard
                val imm = ContextCompat.getSystemService(view.context, InputMethodManager::class.java)
                imm?.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
                //Collapse keyboard
            }
            if(state == STATE_EXPANDED) {
                preState = STATE_EXPANDED
                listener.changeBottomSheetState(STATE_EXPANDED)
                Log.d("state expandedf", "full expanded")

            }
        }

        override fun onSlide(view: View, offset: Float) {
            this.offset = offset
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it! it's `bottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED` when I click the search button